# What methods from SqlMembershipProvider set IsApproved to false?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

I have come across a problem where one of my user's IsApproved flag has magically been set to false and I'm wondering how this may have happened.

The user is not locked out due to failed password attempts (not sure if this would set IsApproved to false) and they have definitely been approved in the past.

Are there any methods in SqlMembershipProvider (the provider I'm using for membership) that set IsApproved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [CreateUserWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.aspx), you can set the [DisableCreatedUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.disablecreateduser.aspx) property to false to force `IsApproved` to be initialized to false for new users.

Otherwise, it's a read-write property that you can set manually - so either you have some code that has done this, or something somewhere has updated the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually setIsapproved property when user is created by this.

Dim MU As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser("ABC")
MU.IsApproved = False

**Membership.UpdateUser(MU)**